# May Jews cut extra vegetables when slicing for immediate eating on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, vegetables, utensil

Halacha permits Jews to cut vegetables on Shabbat for immediate consumption, my question is, if a Jew is doing this anyways, are they allowed to cut extra vegetables (more than they are going to immediately eat) while doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When peeling vegetables (which can be an issue of *borer*) or cutting vegetables (which can be an issue of *tochein*), there is a leniency of doing this close to the meal. However one may not consciously prepare more than required. Clearly this can be a fine line.

Here is how R Daniel Braude describes the allowance ([Learn Shabbos](https://www.feldheim.com/learn-shabbos-in-just-3-minutes-a-day), pp. 184ff)

> One may peel vegetables (with a knife) that are necessary for the
> upcoming meal. **It is forbidden to peel extra vegetables for a later
> meal. However if one is peeling extra vegetables because there is a
> small chance that they will be needed for the current meal or because
> he wants to make the guests feel that the re is more than enough for
> all, it is permitted.**

There are other limitations (e.g., peeling with a knife, not a peeler), doing this right before the meal, cutting in pieces slightly bigger than during the week) so any reader should be sure to learn the *halachot* fully before applying them.

For more see [Mishna Brura 319:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.319.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.319.6&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) and commentaries.